# How to include multiple case statements for multiple columns in the same update statement?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE UPDATE_LEVEL1_LEVEL2 
(
    installment_description varchar(100)
    key_id int
    ITEM_CATEGORY varchar(100)
    ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY varchar(100)
    LEVEL1 varchar(100)
    LEVEL2 varchar(100)
    DEFAULT_VALUE varchar(100) 
)
```

The query below automatically updates LEVEL1 and LEVEL2 based on already mapped records in the table.

```
UPDATE UPDATE_LEVEL1_LEVEL2 ebx
SET ebx.LEVEL1 = config.LEVEL1,
    ebx.LEVEL2 = CASE 
                     WHEN config.ITEM_CATEGORY = 'LOOTCRATE' AND config.=SUB_CATEGORY = 'ND' AND ebx.ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%CLASSIC%' 
                         THEN 'PLAYGROUND'
                     WHEN config.ITEM_CATEGORY = 'LOOTCRATE' AND config.=SUB_CATEGORY = 'ND' AND ebx.ITEM_DESCRIPTION like '%GOLD%' 
                         THEN 'IGLOO'
                     ELSE config.CATEGORY_LEVEL2
                 END
FROM
    (SELECT 
         INSTALLMENT_DESCRIPTION, ITEM_CATEGORY, ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY, 
         LEVEL1, LEVEL2, COUNT(*)
     FROM
         UPDATE_LEVEL1_LEVEL2
     WHERE 
         FLAG_DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT'
     GROUP BY 
         1,2,3,4,5) CONFIG
WHERE
    config.INSTALLMENT_DESCRIPTION = ebx.INSTALLMENT_DESCRIPTION 
    AND config.ITEM_CATEGORY = ebx.ITEM_CATEGORY 
    AND config.ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY = ebx.SUB_CATEGORY 
    AND ebx.LEVEL2 = ''
```

Now, I also need to update the DEFAULT_VALUE column so when the update query runs it also changes all the records in the DEFAULT_VALUE column to "DEFAULT" unless it also contains special words in the description like "CLASSIC" or "GOLD".

Comment: Avoid LEVEL2 inconsistency, either have a trigger to keep the value up to date, or create a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE WHEN here like you do for the column LEVEL2:

```
update UPDATE_LEVEL1_LEVEL2 ebx
set ebx.LEVEL1 = config.LEVEL1,
ebx.DEFAULT_VALUE = case when
ebx.DEFAULT_VALUE like  '%CLASSIC%' or ebx.DEFAULT_VALUE like '%GOLD%' then ebx.DEFAULT_VALUE
else 'DEFAULT'
end,
ebx.LEVEL2 = case
when config.ITEM_CATEGORY = 'LOOTCRATE' and config.=SUB_CATEGORY = 'ND' and ebx.ITEM_DESCRIPTION like '%CLASSIC%' then 'PLAYGROUND'
when config.ITEM_CATEGORY = 'LOOTCRATE' and config.=SUB_CATEGORY = 'ND' and ebx.ITEM_DESCRIPTION like '%GOLD%' then 'IGLOO'
else config.CATEGORY_LEVEL2
end
from (select INSTALLMENT_DESCRIPTION,ITEM_CATEGORY, ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY, LEVEL1, LEVEL2, count(*)
From UPDATE_LEVEL1_LEVEL2
WHERE FLAG_DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5) CONFIG
where config.INSTALLMENT_DESCRIPTION = ebx.INSTALLMENT_DESCRIPTION and
config.ITEM_CATEGORY = ebx.ITEM_CATEGORY and
config.ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY = ebx.SUB_CATEGORY and
ebx.LEVEL2 ='';
```